# sequence twice continously (1,2) based on another value in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sequence

I need to sequence 1,2 based on another column value empid. Per column value i need to have two values in sequence output column

ex dummy data

| empid | deptid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

needed o/p

| empid | deptid | sequence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

we tried with rownumber() partion by but it sequences only once based on another column deptid  but we need to sequence and increment twice 1,2 for single empid

Comment: Your title says "SQL Server" so why have you tagged Oracle too? What RDBMS are you *really* using?

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` to a dataset (such as a `VALUES` table construct) with the values `1` and `2` in it..?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you use MS SQL Server. In that case, one option is to join current table with a *fabricated* one (union of two `select` statements).

Sample table:

```
select * from dummy;

     EMPID     DEPTID
---------- ----------
         1          1
         3          4
```

Query:

```
select d.empid, d.deptid, u.sequence 
from dummy d cross join (select 1 as sequence union all
                         select 2) u;
```

Result:

```
     EMPID     DEPTID   SEQUENCE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1
         1          1          2
         3          4          1
         3          4          2
```

Have a look at [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tJuguh-e).

Comment: `cross join (values (1), (2)) u([sequence])` seems simpler

Comment: By all means, @Charlie, for all of you who speak MS SQL Server. I can hardly spell it so - thank you for comment! I hope OP will use it for his own benefit.